# Compile-time publisher/subscriber pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

In C++ we can [use templates to flexibly implement the publisher/subscriber pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239494/publisher-subscriber-pattern-template).

**Question:** Assuming that I know all publisher/subscriber relations at compile time and there are no unsubscriptions (especially not at run time), how can I implement a compile-time templated publisher/subscriber pattern in C++?

Use case is high-performace data processing in a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG). Data should propagates between the graph nodes via the publisher/subscriber relations. I want to implement the DAG such that the compiler is able to optimize code across (potentially nested) publisher/subscriber relations.

My thoughts:

- I want to have a collection of graph nodes (`FooNode`, `BarNode`, ...) as subclasses to a generic `Node` class. At compile time, I want to link objects of these `FooNode`s, `BarNode`s, ... together via template instantiation (instead of calling a `Node::subscribe` function at run time).
- However, I cannot use pointers to the graph node objects as template parameters, because they get their values only at run time. Something like this cannot work to publish from `pub` to `foo` and `bar`:

  ```cpp
  Node* foo = new FooNode<>();
  Node* bar = new BarNode<>();
  Node* pub = new FooNode<std::tuple<foo, &FooNode<>::cllbck>, std::tuple<bar, &BarNode<>::cllbck>>();
  ```
- Ideally I can define `foo`, `bar` and `pub` in the order from publishers to subscribers, in this example: `pub` goes before `foo`, `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will enable significant optimisation opportunities, but here you go anyway.

```
  struct Event {};

  template <auto& ... subscribers>
  class Publisher
  {
    public:
      void publish(const Event& e)
      {
          (subscribers.notify(e) , ...);
      }
  };

  class Subscriber
  {
    public:
      void notify(const Event&) {}
  };

  template <auto& ... subscribers>
  class Node : public Publisher<subscribers...>, public Subscriber
  {
  };
```

You list the nodes bottom-to-top, subscribers first.

```
  // of course all nodes must have static storage duration 
  Node<> node1;
  Node<node1> node2;
  Node<> node3;
  Node<node1, node2, node3> node4;
```

This is only a skeleton. You can use CRTP to inject different `notify` methods to different subscribers. You can make `publish` a template over the event type to make different subscribers respond to different events. Etc etc.